# In a laravel application with angular, images are not shown

Tags: php, angular, laravel

I have a project in laravel for an API that is on the api.mydomain.com, while the application in angular is on mydomain.com.
The application saves the uploaded images and then shows them, locally everything works correctly, while when I put it on the server (shared server with plesk) it no longer shows me the images I upload and returns a 404 error.
I've already tried running the

```
php artisan storage:link
```

command, but it doesn't create a folder inside public, but only a file without an extension, so I manually create the link with

```
ln -s /path/to/laravel/storage/app/public /path/to/public/storage
```

and that's how it creates the link.
Everything is set correctly in my config file:

```
'disks' => [

    'local' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
        'throw' => false,
    ],

    'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
        'visibility' => 'public',
        'throw' => false,
    ],

],
'links' => [
        public_path('storage') => storage_path('app/public'),
    ],
```

The structure of publis folder is:

> public/storage/app/public/upload/editor/kitsImage/filename.png

while the url leading to the file is:

> api.mydomains.com/storage/upload/editor/kitsImage/filename.png

how come it still doesn't work?

Comment: First, did you check if the file is correctly stored in `public` folder? If files are correctly store, did you confirm the URL path/format is correct corresponding to the saved image in the public folder?

Comment: what is the structure of your `public` folder? What is the URL path of the stored image? (you can omit the domain name)

Comment: In your config, I can see s3 setup, was the image uploaded in s3 instead? A lot of information is missing. Try to update the question with information as detailed as you can.

Comment: Put that in the question, not in comments. Also did you confirm that the image url corresponds where the image is stored in public folder?

Comment: Can you access the image using `api.mydomains.com/editor/kitsImage/filename.png` ?

Comment: I mean access it directly in browser

Comment: @Mr.Kenneth No, it gives me 404

Comment: can you delete the manually created symlink and rerun the symlink method of laravel? After that restart services.

Comment: @Mr.Kenneth I have tried, but as I wrote above running the laravel command does not create the symlink for me, but only a file without an extension called storage

Comment: yes I believe that is the correct symlink for storage and public.

Comment: using that symlink, try to restart services like nginx/apache/etc then access the file again (both what you provided and what I provided)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your `filesystems.local.root` should be:

```
'root' => storage_path('app')`
```

not

```
'root' => storage_path('app/public')
```

also the structure of your public folder after linking should be:

```
public/storage/upload/editor/kitsImage/filename.png
```

not

```
public/storage/app/public/upload/editor/kitsImage/filename.png
```

Comment: I edited the config file and re-launched the command and it created the correct path, but now returns a 403 error

Comment: I have changed the permissions and now it works, thank you.